# If $(x_n)_n$ converges in the co-countable topology on $\mathbb{R}$, then $(\operatorname{Id}(x_n))_n$ converges in the Euclidean topology

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Why is it that for all sequences $(x_n)_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, that if $(x_n)_n$ converges to $x$ with respect to $\mathcal{T}_c$, then $(\operatorname{Id}(x_n))_n$ converges to $x$ with respect to $\mathcal{T}_e$?

Where $\mathcal{T}_c = \{\varnothing\}\cup \{U \subset \mathbb{R} : \mathbb{R}\setminus U \text{ is a countable set}\}$, $\operatorname{Id}\colon (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_c) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_e),\; x \mapsto x$ is the identity function,  $\mathcal{T}_c$ is the co-countable topology, and $\mathcal{T}_e$ is the Euclidean topology.

I have been trying to form a proof for this result from the definitions of convergence in a topology.

Comment: Poorly formated questions tend to get less answers. Try MathJax.

Comment: Can you show that one of these topologies contains the other?

Comment: What is $\operatorname{Id}(x_n)$?

Comment: Can you characterise the sequences that converge in the co-countable topology?

Comment: Ive now  given Id (Xn) and (charaterised the Tc sorry for the poor formatting.

Comment: the sequence $1,1,1,...$ converges to $1$, the sequence $1,0,1,0,..$ has two limit points $0$ and $1$ but converges to neither, and the sequence $a_n=\dfrac1n$ has no limit points at all as the set $\mathbb R\setminus \{\dfrac1n:n=1,2,3..\}$ is open in Tc. Generalize (read @DanielFischer 's comment).